# Finding the asymptotes of an integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I need to find the asymptote of $$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(1 + \frac{x}{\sqrt{n}})}{x + x^3} dx$$

I've taken $b_{n} = n^{-1/2}$ which reduces the problem to finding,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\ \sqrt{n}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(1 + \frac{x}{\sqrt{n}})}{x + x^3} dx$$ but now I'm stuck. Can I bring the limit inside the integral? Am I supposed to show that the limit is equal to 1 so that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 1$?

Comment: What are $a_n$ and $b_n$?

Comment: sorry, I guess $a_{n} = \frac{\ln(1 + \frac{x}{\sqrt{n}})}{x + x^3}$ and $b_{n} = n^{-1/2}$

Comment: @user422504: this doesn't answer the question. What is the definition of $a_n$ and $b_n$ ?

Comment: "Finding the asymptotics of a sequence $(a_{n})$ means providing another
sequence $(b_{n})$ of a simpler form such that $\lim n\to\infty \frac{a_n}{b_n} =1$."

Answer (score 2):

I would use squeezing, with the inequalities
$$
\frac{x}{x+1}<\ln(1+x)<x.
$$
Inserting and calculating, you will find that
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n}\pi-\ln n}{2+2n}\leq \int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\ln(1+x/\sqrt{n})}{x+x^3}\,dx\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{\pi}{2}.
$$
It follows that
$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sqrt{n}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\ln(1+x/\sqrt{n})}{x+x^3}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}.
$$

Comment: Thank you! So does this mean that $\frac{\pi}{2}$ is an asymptote of the given integral?

Comment: If you let $a_n=\int_0^{+\infty}\ln(1+x/\sqrt{n})/(x+x^3)\,dx$ and $b_n=\pi/(2\sqrt{n})$ you will have $\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n/b_n=1$.

Comment: It means your integral is asymptotically equivalent to $\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes sense. Thank you to both of you for helping.

Comment: @mickep I am not sure I fully remember, but this vaguely rings a bell about a more general statement like $$\lim_{n\to\infty} n\int_0^\infty f(x/n)g(x)\, dx = \frac{f'(0)}{2}\int_0^\infty g(x)\, dx$$ does that remind you of anything? (+1, by the way)

Comment: @Clementc I do not remember seing such a formula.